# Page redirect not working in Community change password Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, force.com-sites

Below two cases are not working

Case I : 
In the controller of change password page, there is a redirect to another page based on certain conditions, this page redirect is not occuring.

PageReference ref = Page.resetPasswordPage; return ref;

Case II : 
In Visualforce page we have a apex outputlook link which pointing to another visualforce page, URL is changing but same change password page is coming.

It seems like the page is stuck on change password page.

all the pages are added to communities.

Any information on this would be very helpful.

Comment: Please suggest on how to achieve this.

Comment: does anybody have any idea on this ?

Comment: What action is exactly done before redirection? There may be a chance that the action is failing.